Grafana - Use 2 values instead of one
I'm making a graph in Grafana. My task is to show 2 values. The first value is the percentage of successful checks, the second is the percentage of successful checks that returned a result of 0 (Therefore it is less than or equal to the first one). I wrote 2 queries, but they are displayed as separate lines. That's what I have.
And here's what I want

Is it possible? If not, what is the best option to display this data? There can be many rows, converting each row is a bad idea.
I tried to combine 2 queues into one or change the schedule parameters, but I didn't find anything suitable.
